# How to create an Ember Cli generator?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there any way which can allow us to create our own generator?

Example: ember generate "customized_generator"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ember generate blueprint foo
```

See the official documentation for more information: http://ember-cli.com/extending/#generators-and-blueprints

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way for a blueprint to be generic across every component?